# Django tables connection

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 django tables connected like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to make a query for table `Table` that will get `id_equip` from table `equip`?

**models.py**

```py
class Vendor(models.Model):
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vendor_name
    

class Equipment(models.Model):
    equipment_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id_vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.equipment_name
    
class Table(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id_vend = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    id_equip = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment)
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) is relevant and helpful, I definitely recommend your review at least that section and ideally the whole page.

Your models are already denormalized as evidenced by `Table.id_equip` which relates to `Equipment` so you could do:

```
table = Table.objects.get(SOME_FILTER)
equipment_ids = list(table.id_equip.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
```

If you wanted to go through the vendor I'd suggest:

```
table = Table.objects.get(SOME_FILTER)
equipment_ids = list(Equipment.objects.filter(vendor_set__table_set=table).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

I would recommend that you don't name your relationship fields with `id_`. With an ORM, these fields should represent the instances of the Model they are mapping to. For example:

class Table(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
equipment = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment)

If you're trying to create the model on top of an existing table, you can make use of the [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#db-column) parameter when defining the field.

```
vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, db_column="id_vend")
```